# Independently jumping over full column span rows in the grid regardless of source order

Tags: singularitygs

I'm using singularitygs as my grid system and am really like the flexibility but I have come across a fairly unique situation and I'm not sure if singularity (or any other grid system) addresses

I have a row that span the entire column width, that breaks up the header portion and the content portion of the document. There is an element, div.b, that sits within above the full column bars next to div.a in larger layout. But on a medium sized layout and below, that element falls below the full span row. Here is the source order and the desired output, showed using a 10 column layout for simplicity.

**Source Order**

```
div.a
div.b
div.c
div.d
div.e
div.f
div.g
div.h
```

**Large Layout**
[image: Large layout in grid]

**Medium Layout**
[image]

Thanks in advance for any help and ++ to the creators of the grid system

Answer (score 1):

Interesting use case. Honestly it’s going to be pretty hard until CSS grid layout comes out. While Singularity can handle any order horizontally, the vertical reordering like "D" and "G" stacked is going to be tricky. There might be a clever use of floats to get this working but it will probably be more hand manipulation of elements than pure Singularity magic.

Comment: Thanks for the input scott, I think the D an G stacking is less of an issue than the jumping over a full column span element. I agree this might be helped when grid layouts become available. And in the interim, I might solve by keeping the rows that need to be jumped over, independent of the grid.

Comment: In that case, I made a quick example of how to do the large layout: http://codepen.io/scottkellum/pen/gCeaF — combining the vertically stacked columns. Because there is much more vertical reorganization in the medium layout I didn’t attempt.